# Errors while import universe VNC_env

Tags: python

Im getting this error while importing universe into my project,

I have reinstalled go-vncdriver but still no luck. Any one know about this?

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
File "/Users/uzirthapa/PycharmProjects/NeuralNetV1/universetest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import universe
File "/Users/uzirthapa/PycharmProjects/NeuralNetV1/universe/universe/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from universe import error, envs
File "/Users/uzirthapa/PycharmProjects/NeuralNetV1/universe/universe/envs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import universe.envs.vnc_env
File "/Users/uzirthapa/PycharmProjects/NeuralNetV1/universe/universe/envs/vnc_env.py", line 11, in <module>
    from universe.envs import diagnostics
File "/Users/uzirthapa/PycharmProjects/NeuralNetV1/universe/universe/envs/diagnostics.py", line 94
    async = self.qr_pool.apply_async(self.method, (self._last_img, time.time(), available_at))
      ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thank you!

Comment: question is not correctly formatted. So add formatting on question contents.

Answer (score -1):

Open your universe/universe/envs/diagnostics.py
and rename all(4) async to another unique word.
In this example async is renamed to blubb.

94:                **blubb** = self.qr_pool.apply_async(self.method, (self._last_img, time.time(), available_at))

95:            self.deque.append(**blubb**)

---

260:                **blubb** = self.pool.imap_unordered(

261:                self._add_metadata_i,

262:                zip(self.instance_n, observation_n, info_n, [available_at] * len(observation_n)))

263:            list(**blubb**)